# Unable to compile my Latex project to produe PDF in arxiv

Tags: errors, compiling, compilation-error, arxiv, terminal-output

I am trying to upload a .zip folder that contains my latex project for a paper. The project compiles successfully in my machine. However, I receive some fatal errors which seems mysteryous to me. I am copying the fatal errors whcih I could not indentify their reasosn. Note that the zip fodler I am uploading contains:

```
img ==> (contains .eps files) 
sec ==> (contains .tex files)
main.tex
main.bbl
IEEEtran
IEEEtran.cls
```

The template file:

```
IEEEtran

IEEEtran.cls
```

The main file:

```
main.tex
```

The biblography file:

```
main.bbl
```

A folder named `img` which contains images in `.eps` format

A folder named `sec` which contains `.tex` files

The arxiv processing log:

```
l.305 \AtEndPreamble
{%
?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.305 \AtEndPreamble
{%
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: latex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1622181837 >= 1622181836)
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running pdflatex for the first time ~~~~~~~~

.....
l.305 \AtEndPreamble
{%
?
! Emergency stop.
...

l.305 \AtEndPreamble
{%
! ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: pdflatex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: Removing (La)TeX AUX file called 'main.aux' (1622181838 >= 1622181837)
[verbose]: 'htex' is not a valid TeX format; will ignore.
[verbose]: TEXMFCNF is unset.
[verbose]: ~~~~~~~~~~~ Running tex for the first time ~~~~~~~~
[verbose]: Running: "(export HOME=/tmp PATH=/texlive/2020/bin/arch:/bin; cd /submissions/3764465/ && tex 'main.tex' < /dev/null)" 2>&1
[verbose]: This is TeX, Version 3.14159265 (TeX Live 2020) (preloaded format=tex)
(./main.tex
! Undefined control sequence.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
?
! Emergency stop.
l.1 \documentclass
[journal,comsoc]{IEEEtran}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on main.log.

[verbose]: tex 'main.tex' failed.
[verbose]: We failed utterly to process the TeX file 'main.tex'
[error]: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.
*** AutoTeX ABORTING ***

[verbose]: AutoTeX returned error: Unable to sucessfully process tex files.

[verbose]: $autotex->process failed $@: $?: 0 $!: Inappropriate ioctl for device
[verbose]: Error running AutoTeX process:
```

Comment: well the error message seems to say that `\AtEndPreamble` is not defined. You need to load etoolbox for it.

Comment: @Ulrike Fischer do you mean I should add: \usepackage{etoolbox}? I tried that but this did not solve the problem.

Comment: It must have solved the problem that `\AtEndPreamble` is not defined (as long as you loaded it before the package giving the error), you may have other errors too, that you haven't shown.